# Angular: Programatically adding multiple y-axes to highstock with navigator

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I have an issue, but I might simply be doing something wrong. My requirement is for a trend where the user can add or remove custom y-axes during runtime. Our project uses Angular and the official highcharts-angular wrapper.

What I've been doing is constructing the axis configuration objects and pushing them into the yAxis array in the configuration. I also set the update option before adding each object, and the objects themselves are assembled and added correctly.

The problem is that the first axis I add is displayed as if it applies to the navigator instead of the main plot, and any subsequent ones are ignored (though they correctly appear in the configuration object).

[yAxis appears in navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdZre.png)

When I add the same axis manually into the initial configuration object, it displays correctly. However, any dynamically added ones follow the same pattern from that point onward (first one added is displayed in the navigator and the others are not displayed at all).

[axis from config object appears normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmmWG.png)

Am I doing something wrong? Should I somehow fetch the chart object and call addAxis? Seems like there must be a more straightforward, proper angular way to do it. Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update: Including an "id" property to the dynamically added axis breaks even this behavior, instead throwing a highcharts error 18 upon adding it to the array.

Error 18 is: The requested axis does not exist - This error happens when you set a series' xAxis or yAxis property to point to an axis that does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this a while ago; answering here in case anyone else runs into a similar problem.

I found no solution that doesn't include using the chart object. This object has all the relevant methods for updating a chart and they work. If you need a (relatively) elegant way of getting this object in an angular project, consider doing it in the predefined load event like this:

```
const component = this;
this.chartOptions = {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        component.chartObject = this; // expose chart object to component in order to  properly add and remove axes
      }
    }
  }
}
```